# Call to undefined function ibase_connect()

Tags: php, error-handling, firebird2.5

```
Call to undefined function ibase_connect()
```

Continue to give me this error, I also tried to modify the php.ini, but still the same. I don't know what else I can do

Comment: Start with what https://www.php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php explains …?

Comment: where I should type this " --with-interbase[=DIR]" ?

Comment: That’s an option you would have to set when _compiling_ PHP. But that is relevant only for *nix systems, if you are on Windows, you have to follow the instructions regarding placement of the DLL files instead.